# Sync multiple gmail contacts with Lion Address Book?

Tags: data-synchronization, gmail, contacts, google-sync

I understand that Address Book, even on Lion, doesn't support syncing multiple gmail contacts. Is there a third-party app that I can use for this purpose? I'm looking for an app that gives me a combined view of all my address books, like iOS or Android contacts apps. I'm not okay giving my gmail passwords to a web site. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

[Cobook](http://www.cobookapp.com/) seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually it's not -- Cobook does not sync with GMail. It syncs with Facebook and Twitter, and also shows you contacts from your Address Book, which you're expected to set up to sync with Gmail. Which brings us back to square one: Address Book supports only one Gmail account.

Comment: indeed you are right. looked promising though